# Centering about enumerated text

Tags: enumerate

Is there a way to center an image about the enumerated text, rather than with respect to the document itself? So instead of the image being equidistant from the counter and the other side of the text, have it be centered within the (indented/enumerated) paragraph. An example is given below, and a MWE is given as well.:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[5]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 1.5]{test}
\end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that a float goes to some lengths _not_ to inherit the current line settings as the whole point of floats is that they may be moved to a different location (even with `[!ht]` which most often generates a warning and is changed to `[!ht]`)

Comment: Nonetheless, I need to both keep the figure environment (I need a caption/ figure label!) and also need to center my image with respect to the text... (I suppose I should have written that in my example- I had forgotten.)

Comment: No, if the image _needs_ to be in that position then it _needs_ not to be a float which is the same as saying it shouldn't be a figure. You can use `\caption` and `\label` anyway using `\captionof{figure}{..}`

Comment: Oh I can? And I see. I submit! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

That is the default behaviour for centering of material within the item.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[5]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, but what if I want to keep my figure environment?

Comment: @Anthony Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Anthony you don't. That was an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I commented on the question- I actually still need the caption and figure label.

Comment: @Anthony that is not the same as saying you need a figure environment. A float environment is not really about captioning it is about _moving_ hence its name "float".

Comment: @Anthony did you see my answer? I suggest there how to get caption and label.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. I have a long way to go before reaching LaTeX enlightenment! 

And @GonzaloMedina yeah, I'd rather avoid using another package if I need to though, my heads already spinning!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I suppose OP's going to accept your answer (you were a second or two earlier) and you'll stay ahead of me for another day or so:(

Comment: @Anthony If you don't want another package you could copy the contents of capt-of.sty into your document (it's one line long:-)

Comment: @Anthony as David says, it's easy to avoid additional packages (I gave the example in my updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `figure`, you can use a `minipage` of width equal to `\linewidth`; an eventual caption can be provided using `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages; `\centering` can be replaced with a `center` environment to add some vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item \lipsum[5] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{example-image-a} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

An example with `\caption` and `\label` to cross-reference:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 
\begin{document}
As we see in Figure~\ref{fig:test}... 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item \lipsum[5] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{example-image-a} 
\captionof{figure}{test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{minipage} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

And without additional packages (adding directly the definition of `\captionof` from `capt-of`):

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
As we see in Figure~\ref{fig:test}... 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item \lipsum[5] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{example-image-a} 
\captionof{figure}{test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{minipage} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```